# cx_Oracle connection to kerberized db crashes

Tags: python, cx-oracle

I am using cx_Oracle to connect to remote kerberized oracle db.

```
import cx_Oracle
dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn('<hostname>','<port>',service_name='<service_name>')
con = cx_Oracle.connect(dsn=dsn_tns,user="<user>")
```

This same code was working till only a few days back, but now it crashes with the following error message. I don't know how this issue can be reproduced.

Windows Prompt Error:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: python.exe
  Application Version:  3.7.150.1013
  Application Timestamp:    5b331a30
  Fault Module Name:    KERNELBASE.dll
  Fault Module Version: 6.1.7601.24563
  Fault Module Timestamp:   5fae08d0
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 000000000000b87d
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.4
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: cb1c
  Additional Information 2: cb1c85eb73e69a06d2e8c780e8325b32
  Additional Information 3: 3935
  Additional Information 4: 393568d2fdb6ac418d437663b21cf147
```

Terminal error:

```
ORA-24550: signal received: Unhandled exception: Code=c0000005 Flags=0

kpedbg_dmp_stack()+387<-kpeDbgCrash()+94<-kpeDbgSignalHandler()+119<-skgesig_Win_UnhandledExceptionFilter()+167<-0000000076ECB970<-00000000770C8515<-00000000770A6798<-00000000770BB41D<-000000007708F77A<-0
0000000770BAABE<-000007FEE4856EF8<-000007FEA8FBB141<-000007FEA911A132<-000007FEA911EE1F<-000007FEA91235AC<-000007FEA904088D<-ttcdrv()+1464<-000007FEA9063C2C<-xupirtrc()+1703<-xupirtr()+194<-xupiver()+215<
-upiver()+25<-kpusrel()+1498<-OCIServerRelease()+111<-kpu8lgn()+14276
```

However I am able to connect to the db directly using sqldeveloper, so I dont think there's any error with the connection to db.
Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: You can contact Oracle Support and ask them to help; otherwise, you'll have to figure out what changed and see if you can find a consistent way to replicate the issue. If you do find a way to replicate consistently, log an issue on the cx_Oracle GitHub page: https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/issues

Comment: Any way you could suggest to figure out what has changed?

Comment: Not really. You need to think about what things have taken place between the time that it was working and the time that it stopped working -- and then test each of those changes to find out which one was the culprit. Did the code change? Did the database change? Did the client change? Did the configuration files change? Did the network configuration change? And so forth!